# trigger save old record in another column in the same table oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table called customer_history 
where it includes customer_id, Visit_Date, Action_Done
i added 2 new columns old_visit_date, old_action_date and created the following trigger where when updating visit_date the old date column to be add into old_action_date column as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_history 
  BEFORE UPDATE
 OF visit_date
 ON TESTING FOR EACH ROW
Declare visit_date date;
BEGIN
:NEW.old_visit_date    := visit_date ; 
END;
/
```

however when updating the table the old_visit_date is not updated ????!!!!

Comment: Maybe because it is trigger on TESTING table, not customer_history? And code should be `:NEW.old_visit_date    := :OLD.visit_date` ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
BEGIN
   IF UPDATING ('VISIT_DATE') THEN 
       :NEW.old_visit_date    := OLD.visit_date ; 
   END IF;
END;
```

/